# asking about android:installLocation on manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

so i learned the syntax for the **installLocation** for the **android manifest**, 
in the  i typed the android:installLocation as an attribute and it has an error, but when i remove the android: part and just leave the installLocation everything works out, my minsdk is 7 targeted is 8, 
i use emulator 2.1 update 1.

i just want to make sure that there is nothing wrong with this, if this is just normal? cause all the syntax sample includes the android: part of the code?

i have screenshots, but new members are not allowed to upload photos apparently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, the thing is that `installLocation` supports on Android Ver2.2(froyo) and above