# Android: installLocation

Tags: android

I'm new in Android, I was trying to set `installLocation` in manifest, I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582311/asking-about-androidinstalllocation-on-manifest) that my minsdk should be Ver2.2(froyo) and above.
here in my mainfest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ir.royalplus.guessyourcar"
android:versionCode="1"
android:installLocation="auto"
android:versionName="3.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

but I still have this error:

```
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'installLocation' in package 'android'
```

what is wrong with my code?!

Comment: I change it to 8 but I still have that error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`android:installLocation` was introduced with API level `8`. Since your `minSdkVersion="7"` is lower than 8 it is not supported. To solve this issue set your `minSdkVersion` to 8 or higher.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html)

Comment: Make sure to also update your project structure as well as the min sdk version in your build system or ide.

Comment: I got it, TnX keyboardsurfer

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install) - installLocation, Introduced in: API Level 8.  Your current min is 7, so it'll throw an error.  To fix this, just change your min to 8.